# triggering transitionend and ending the transition

Tags: javascript

hey guys i am basically trying to end a transition by calling the transitionend event , the event fires but the transition does't end , i am a bit confused , have a look at my code below :

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    $('.test').trigger('transitionend');
});

$('.test').on('transitionend', function () {
    console.log('transition ended');
});
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a1L3wfku/)**

See how the transition still continuous , even after you click the `button` . can somebody explain why i am not able to stop the transition ?

Comment: So, can we assume you're also using some sort of JS framework and not just vanilla JS?

Comment: AFAIK the end of the transition produces a `transitionend` event, not the opposite.

Comment: @ElGuapo prefer chocolate , but been using Jquery :)

Answer (score 2):

`transitionend` is an event fired by the browser, you do not fire it yourself. It lets you know that a transition has ended, it does not make a transition end.

You have specified that the transition is `100s` so it will take that long.

If you want to transition to be disabled when you click, you'd have to add a class on click that removed the transition styling.